# Movement/transform gizmo isn't "flat"

Tags: animation, bones, gizmo

I'm a complete newbie to Blender and have been following a couple tutorials about viewmodel animation. An issue I've run into though is that when I select anything, be it a model or a part of an armature or a bone or whatever, the movement gizmo is not positioned correctly. [image: Gizmo isn't "flat"...] I have no idea when this happened or why, and I don't know what kind of question to search to find a solution. Help/guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To add some clarity: I have everything set to global position, so I don't know why it's askew. I genuinely don't know how else to describe this situation.

Comment: Still looking for help.

Comment: could you please share your file? upload and copy paste the URL it will give: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/1624509f058d4f72a40b14a078fa2b35 Here you go moonboots

Comment: @moonboots sorry to ping but I forgot to in my previous comment. I'm still having this issue and still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've disabled the *Header > Show Tool Settings* option of your header menu, which is currently at the bottom of your 3D view, right click on the header menu to display this pop-up then choose *Header* and enable the *Show Tool Settings* option:

[image]

Now you can see some additional functions, like this *Orientation* dropdown panel, it overrides the orientation you've selected in the *Transform Orientation* panel, choose *Default* instead of *Cursor*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it!